# Security on a mysqli query

Tags: php, security, mysqli, xss, sql-injection

The question refers to a simple Form using POST method to send data to the server.I am interested in some cases:

1] Data come from a Form Textbox

2] Data come from a Form Listbox

3] Data are used to enter new data in the database

4] Data are used in a query after WHERE to filter out results

**Question 1: Is a query safe vs SQL Injections in all combination of the above cases? If not what can I do to make sure I did my best in keeping my code as secure as possible?**

What makes me sceptical is that I included the  $ComparisonB variable in the mysqli query, using prepared statements though.

**Question 2: Assuming we sanitize $ComparisonB vs XSS using the following** method:

```
function xssanitize($data,$encoding='UTF-8')
{
   return htmlspecialchars($data,ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401,$encoding);
}
```

Is it sufficient or should I do something more?

I KNOW that "Security is a state of mind", but I would like to learn to do things as proper as possible.

Comment: no. your sanitize function is utterly useless for sql injection protection. html escaping has absolutely **NOTHING** to do with sql. it's like putting a bandaid on a bonfire.

Comment: XSS is different question than the first. I want to check for both SQL injection AND XSS protection. They say that prepared statements are sufficient vs SQLinjection, is it true?

Comment: Thanks for the link on the previous answered question.